# Can Skulk parasites destroy mines?

Tags: natural-selection-2

I've noticed that shooting a deployed mine with a parasite will deal 10 damage to it, but after firing two or three I've always been shooed away by pesky gunfire (if there are Marines around) or opted to leave it alone in favor of a more valuable target (if there aren't).

Can parasites actually destroy/detonate a mine from a distance? If so, how many will it take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too many to be worth the effort. Just walk around it. Mines have 80 hp. So it will take 8 parasites. That's more than your initial energy pool.